# Genericity of contact structures all of whose closed Reeb orbits are nondegenerate

Tags: differential-topology, contact-geometry, periodic-orbit

First, a contact form $\alpha$ on $M$ with Reeb vector field $R$ is said to be **non-degenerate** if, for any point $p$ such that $\phi_T^R(p) = p$, we have $\det{(\textrm{id}_{T_pM} - (d \phi_T^R)_p)} \neq 0$.

It seems to be widely known that the set of nondegenerate contact forms is generic (I guess it means dense here) in the set of all contact forms. However, I'm unable to find a "clean" proof in the existing literature, except in Bourgeois' notes "Introduction to Contact Homology" which can be found here: [https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~bourgeois/papers/Berder.pdf](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebourgeois/papers/Berder.pdf), Lemma 2 on Page 3. However, there are quite a few things that are unclear to me about the proof written here. I will try to point them out as specifically as possible:

- In the first step, for $\gamma$ a degenerate closed orbit through $p$, and $f_p$ a function such that $df_p =0$ along $\gamma$ and supported in a tubular neighborhood of $\gamma$ why is it okay to take $(1 + \epsilon f_p)\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$ for small enough $\epsilon$?
- After that, it is said that the linearized flow (of $R_{(1+\epsilon f_p)\alpha}$, I assume) along $\gamma$ has the additional term $$\frac{\epsilon}{(1+\epsilon f_p)^2} J\textrm{Hess}(f_p)$$for a compatible complex structure $J$ on the contact structure $\xi$. I'm not sure that $\gamma$ remains a closed orbit of $R_{(1+\epsilon f_p)\alpha}$, and I suspect that it doesn't. Also, how does one perform this calculation of the linearized flow, and where does a compatible complex structure come up?
- Perhaps most importantly, it is said that, for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, no closed orbit of period $\leq T$ will be created by this perturbation. Why?

I would be grateful for any additional information regarding this folklore-type result - a different reference, some additional explanations of the proof I linked, or anything else that would shed some light on this.

Comment: Other (related) proofs exist, such as Appendix A of Albers-Bramham-Wendl (*"On nonseparating contact hypersurfaces in symplectic 4–manifolds"*), and Lemma 7.1 of Colin-Honda (*"Reeb vector fields and open book decompositions"*), and Proposition 6.1 of Hofer-Wysocki-Zehnder (*"The Dynamics on Three-Dimensional Strictly Convex Energy Surfaces"*) though that crucially refers to a result of Robinson.

Comment: A very useful document when learning this stuff, assuming you can read French-Math, is Jean Gutt's masters thesis *"Dynamique de Reeb et Homologie de Contact".* Also you should supplement Bourgeois' paper with his PhD thesis (*"A Morse-Bott approach to contact homology"*) which rephrases the proof in Section 2.2 without mentioning $J$, for example.

Comment: 1st bullet: This is an example of a very small perturbation! 2nd bullet: Remember that $f|_\gamma=1$ and $df|_\gamma=0$ (also the linearization of the Reeb flow is not the Reeb field). Perform the calculation carefully by invoking the definitions of what it means to be a Reeb vector field, and as for J you're essentially using a metric which is compatible with $d\alpha$ on the contact structure (normal planes to the Reeb orbit) to discuss Hessians/gradients. 3rd bullet: Argue by contradiction and Arzelà-Ascoli theorem (supposing there exists new orbits as $\epsilon\to0$).

Comment: A possibly helpful comment (especially for the second bullet point): Suppose we know $R_{\alpha}$, and we take $g$ a nonzero function. Then $R_{g\alpha} = \frac{1}{g}(R_{\alpha} + V_g)$, where $V_g$ is the symplectic gradient of $\ln(g)$, i.e. the unique vector field in $\xi$ defined by $d\alpha(V_g,\cdot) = d\ln(g)$. For example, in the case $g = 1+\epsilon f$, the condition that $df = 0$ along the Reeb orbit $\gamma$ is precisely what ensures that $\gamma$ remains a Reeb orbit $\gamma$, which is clear from this computation (since $V_g = 0$ along $\gamma$).

Comment: @ChrisGerig Thanks so much for your comments! They were very helpful, but I hope you don't mind if I annoy you with another question, concerning the second bullet point: I thought I was sure what "linearized flow" meant - if $\phi_t$ is the flow of the perturbed Reeb field, then I assume that this means $d\phi_t$ - now I'm not so sure anymore. If I'm right, how do I start this calculation? Do I write $\phi_t(x+h) - \phi_t(x) = \cdots$ in a chart, or...?

Comment: I looked at the additional references you gave me: the Albers-Bramham-Wendl proof seemed great to me, but something about the Reeb field calculation seems off to me: the $X_{f \lambda}$-component of $\hat{X}$ is $-\hat{f}/f$, not $-\hat{f}$, and if that is taken into account, the vector field called $V_{\hat{f}}$ doesn't satisfy the property labelled (A.3). I could be wrong, of course, but I've checked my calculation enough times to say something. I don't know if it matters in the long run... Also, do you know of a place where I could find Jean Gutt's masters thesis? It's not on his website.